# Laravel - Simple foreach inside foreach - not updating the model with firstOrNew

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Very simple task. Getting multiple data (invoices) from an API.

```
foreach($items->data as $item) {
        $invoice = Invoice::firstOrNew(array('invoice_number' => $item->DocumentNo));
        $invoice->total = $item->GrandTotal;
        $invoice->save();
        $m = 0;

        foreach ($item->lines as $product) {
          $productModel = Product::find(1)->where('unique_id', '=', $product->Product)->first();
          if(isset($productModel)) {
              $productToInvoice = ProductToInvoice::firstOrNew(array('product_id' => $productModel->product_id, 'invoice_id' => $invoice->id));
              $productToInvoice->total = $product->LineNetAmt;
              $productToInvoice->quantity = $product->QtyEntered;
              $productToInvoice->price = $product->PriceEntered;
              $productToInvoice->save();
          }
          $m++;
        }
}
```

`$item->lines` are the products inside the invoice. Data coming from the API. I connect this data to my `Product` model with this line:
`$productModel = Product::find(1)->where('unique_id', '=', $product->Product)->first();`

When the invoice doesn't exist, everything seems to be ok. Product lines are added correctly.
When the invoice exists (and also the product lines): it updates the lines but `total`, `quantity` and `price` are the same for all lines.

EDIT: If you `var_dump($m)` inside the loop - it will print 0, 1 (for 2 lines) but if you save, for example `productToInvoice->price = $m` it will save 1 for each entry / line.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is such a weird behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$productToInvoice->total = $productModel->LineNetAmt;      // $productModel insted of $product
$productToInvoice->quantity = $productModel->QtyEntered;  // $productModel insted of $product
$productToInvoice->price = $productModel->PriceEntered;   // $productModel insted of $product
```

Comment: `Product`,  as an entity has different details inside the app. $item->lines is coming from an API and has different prices and always other quantities. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this line
`Product::find(1)`
you are finding Product with `id` 1 every time.
that line should be

`$productModel = Product::where('unique_id', '=', $product->Product)->first();`

Comment: I already tried that. I thought this was the problem too. But no, everything stays the same. It actually finds the products in my database. but it cannot update them. Looks like the foreach is broken :)